# After minimize/restore the EULA window the information disappeared

Tags: wix

I'm using ScrollableText control to display EULA and everything works fine except the following scenario: 
When EULA dialog is displayed select some word(s) then minimize the EULA window. After restoring the window whole license information disappeared. But after selecting some area in the control the EULA text is appears.

Could somebody help me to understand the root cause of the problem.

I have tried it with 3.0.5419.0 build on WindowsXP SP3 and Windows Installer 4.5 and have the same problem.

The WIX source is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

    <?define ProductName="WixProject"?>
    <?define ProductVersion="1.0.1"?>
    <?define Manufacturer="WixProject"?>
    <?define Language="1033"?>
    <?define ProductCode="{830E8896-AD07-4fbb-8828-4165D2C84887}"?>
    <?define UpcradeCode="{BA074C59-1F12-4a95-8BD8-177E18234AB3}"?>

    <Product Id='$(var.ProductCode)'
         Version='$(var.ProductVersion)'
         Name='$(var.ProductName)'
         Language='$(var.Language)'
         Manufacturer='$(var.Manufacturer)'
         UpgradeCode='$(var.UpcradeCode)'>

        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

        <Upgrade Id='$(var.UpcradeCode)'>
            <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" IncludeMaximum="no"    Property="OLD_VERSION_FOUND" Maximum='$(var.ProductVersion)' />
        </Upgrade>

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="WixProject1">
                    <Component Id="ReadMeC" Guid="{3DC5A180-EC42-4466-8E4B-1BA37BFF189C}" SharedDllRefCount="yes" Win64="no">
                        <File Id="ReadMeF" Name="ReadMe.txt" Source="ReadMe.txt" Vital="yes" />
                    </Component>
                </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <FindRelatedProducts Sequence="200" />
            <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallFinalize' />
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="WixProject1" Level="1">
            <ComponentRef Id="ReadMeC" />
        </Feature>

        <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

This is the very simple WIX file which installs only one file and uses WixUI_Minimal UI.
Even for this installer I can see the same problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked about this issue from the WIX developers and they say that the problem is in the Windows Installer RichEdit control.

For details please refer to the link below:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=642714&aid=3087369&group_id=105970

Answer (score 1):

The ScrollableText control is quite limited (as well as MSI UI in general). It's hard for me to point out the exact reason of such behavior, but probably one of [Rob's suggestions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2006/05/30/610950.aspx) helps (for instance, re-save your license.rtf in WordPad and try again).

It would also be interesting to know what exactly helped (when you manage to dig it out). :-)

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately re-save doesn't help. Actually my rtf works fine, it is displayed correctly even after minimize/restore EULA dialog. Only when some text is selected before minimize/restore it is gone.

Answer (score 1):

All of my InstallShield installers don't even the minimize button enabled and I've never missed it.  My WiX installers have minimize capabilities but I haven't reproduced your problem.  What version of MSI do you have installed?   Can you repro this on different machines with different versions?

I can reproduce this behavior using WiX's own installer.  I guess I've just never tried to select some text then minimize the installer before.   This is clearly a defect in MSI's internal UI and there isn't going to be anything you can do about it other then not enable the Minimize button like InstallShield does.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this issue inder XP and Vista. Honestly i didn't try it under Windows 7. WIX version is 3.0.2925.0. MSI version is 4.5 (for Vista).

Comment: WiX 3.0 RTM'd nearly a year and a half ago with build 3.0.5419.0.  I can't imagine why you are using build 2925 or that it would be the source of your problem.  Does an off the shelf installer ( say WiX 3.0 ) have the same RTF problem using the same machines?

Comment: Please see my comments and WIX source above.