# Using WiX 3.8 - how to make sure the EULA is actually properly displayed initially?

Tags: wix, wix3.8, eula

I have a WiX 3.8 setup project for a plugin I'm writing, and while most of the stuff works fine, displaying the EULA seems to be a challenge.

I have the RTF file at hand - and I have referenced it in my setup like this:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="EULA\MyEula2.rtf" />
```

That file exists, it's a valid RTF (converted from a Winword document) - but when I launch my setup (from the MSI), I get this screen:

[image]

Where's the EULA?!?!? It's there - it's just not visible at first. I need to wiggle around the form, play around with the mouse for a bit, and suddenly the text shows up.

Not a really good user experience..... any ideas why that behavior happens?

Comment: That is an issue with Word documents. Open and save the file in WordPad and I believe it will fix the issue.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930984/after-minimize-restore-the-eula-window-the-information-disappeared

Comment: @BryanJ: WOW ! Interesting..... never would have assumed that - but you're right, open in Wordpad, save under a new name - and presto! Everything works as expected! If you add this as an answer, I'll be able to accept it soon enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug can occur with RTF files saved in Microsoft Word. A workaround is to open and save the file in another application, such as Wordpad.

Related: [After minimize/restore the EULA window the information disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930984/after-minimize-restore-the-eula-window-the-information-disappeared)